# android read usb asynchronously

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, usb

I'm trying to read a string from Arduino on Android device asynchronously, using a library downloaded here

https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

I managed to do it, but the code works only once and not in a loop cycle.
I've tryed to do it in asyncTask but the program crashes, so i managed to do the cycle by executing a runnable in loop, but the program freezes every time the runnable is executed, and un-freeze when the runnable ends the work.

This is the code used to read from the usb:

```
try
{
     UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
     driver = UsbSerialProber.acquire(manager);
     if (driver != null) {

            driver.open();
            driver.setBaudRate(9600);
            new Thread(runnable).start();
            buffer = new byte[3000];
                    numBytesRead = driver.read(buffer, 3000);
                String str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                buffer = null;
                numBytesRead = 0;
        }
}
catch(Exception ex){//do nothing}
```

I structured the runnable to be executed this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
try
{
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
     driver = UsbSerialProber.acquire(manager);
     if (driver != null) {

            driver.open();
            driver.setBaudRate(9600);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1);
        }
}
catch(Exception ex){//do nothing}
}



private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
                buffer = new byte[3000];
                numBytesRead = driver.read(buffer, 3000);
                String str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                buffer = null;
                numBytesRead = 0;
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1);  //here is where the runnable is executed again. This generates the loop
              } 
        catch (IOException e) {//do nothing}    
       }
    };
```

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I changed the parameter 1 in

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1);
```

and

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
```

to

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
```

and also i've changed the buffer size here:

```
buffer = new byte[3000];
numBytesRead = driver.read(buffer, 3000);
```

from 3000 to 40, that's the reason why the program was so slow.

Thank you anyway!